# How can i get the TRect of the whole content of the RichEdit?

Tags: delphi, format, richedit

How can i get the TRect of the whole content of the RichEdit?

i have a function to save the richEdit as image using the TRangeformat, but the problem is we are the one to define the rect where to be printed. how can i get the exact rect to print the whole content?

thnax

Comment: do you mean **A:** the visible rect? or do you want to include that part **B:** which is scrolled offscreen as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text extent of RichEdit in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244139/how-to-get-text-extent-of-richedit-in-delphi)

Comment: @Sertac Excellent work. I read the documentation for `FORMATRANGE` but nowhere in there does it say that the `rc` member is an `IN/OUT` parameter and that the `OUT` value is the rendered to extent. Once again I bow before your superior knowledge of the Windows API.

Comment: @David - I don't think my win api knowledge is any better than yours, not in general.  I feel spoiled with a compliment coming from you anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of example on how to make windows paint a canvas with Delphi. Here is one that might help.

> Painting a Rich Edit control onto a
>   bitmap for preview

http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/Print_Preview.aspx

And some more:
[Measuring size full text of TRichEdit](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200604/0604024539.html)