# Set height of richedit to skip scrollbar

Tags: delphi, height, richedit

How can I change the height of A richedit, so that the text is fully displayed and the scrollbar disapears.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the RichEdit height property so that it is big enough.

```
RichEdit1.Height := Max(MinHeight, RichEdit1.Lines.Count * LineHeight);
```

`MinHeight` is the minimum `heigth` you accept (for example empty `RichEdit`).
`LineHeight` is the mean heigth of the lines. Depends on the font height and content of the `RichEdit` which is potentially highly variable.

The question you have not asked "How to get text extent in a RichEdit" is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244139/how-to-get-text-extent-of-richedit-in-delphi).

Comment: Thanks but how we calculate LineHeight parameter?

Comment: @AmirTofighi: That is exactly what is explained in the linked answer.